# App2sd - Changing the SD Card

Tags: external-sd, app2sd

I plan to purchase a new micro SD card for my phone, I use app2SD for most of my programs, so what I wonder is what will happen if I get the new SD card, will I be able to copy the content of the old card onto the new card and still operate the phone as if nothing was changed?

Comment: what if the card had ext file sustem?
I think you might need to migrate /sd-ext data also to new card

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I did that myself, like this:

1. power the phone off and remove the old SD card
2. mount the old SD on a PC, copy its entire contents somewhere on your hard disk
3. mount the new SD card on a PC, format it as FAT or FAT32 (make sure it's the same file-system as the old one)
4. copy the contents of the old SD card onto the new one
5. insert the new SD card into the phone, power it on.

Comment: I am not sure how that works.. some apps still take up space on the internal space even if it was 'app2sd-ed'..

Comment: That doesn't matter. As long as the SD files are copied 1:1 on the new card, everything will work fine. As I said, I did it myself and had zero problems.

Comment: Did it retain all the settings, userdata etc? or just the apps

Comment: Yes, *everything* was exactly as before changing the SD card - only a bit faster as the new card is Class 4 while the old one was Class 2 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually know for sure, but you can certainly test it out. You can turn on USB debugging, which will let you mount your phone as any other external drive, or you can get a micro-SD adaptor if you have an SD slot already.

It should just work.